# Can we hide part of an URL?

Tags: java, http, url

I want it so that when you click a link, the browser will only show the folder it directed you to, rather than the whole address.

Ex:

```
folder/
```

rather than

```
127.0.0.1/folder/
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Hm, that would be why I found nothing looking it up.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe the reason you found nothing is because the people that asked this on SO got down-voted and decided to delete their question.  +1 to compensate, and because - it is a valid question that is easily answered.  In fact..

Comment: Is the question tagged correctly, do you mean Java or Javascript?

Comment: @PeterJ I mean Java, In a Java browser I am working on

Comment: @Airis reason I asked and probably the reason for all the initial downvotes is that changes things a bit and many probably assumed JS. But if you're writing a Java browser from scratch can't you just display whatever you like? Otherwise if you're modifying / using something already existing in pure Java there may be other solutions, but you'd need to be a bit more specific how you're going about it.

Comment: @PeterJ Oh, I see, should I rewrite the question?

Comment: @Airis If you're writing your own I'd probably start a new question with a description and code of how you're going about it at the moment. Probably a description of why you want to achieve it too help because it is pretty non-standard behaviour and many might wonder if it's for something malicious.

Comment: @PeterJ Ok, I will do that later today, I have to go to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we hide part of an URL?

No, it isn't possible.   The correct form of an URI/URL is clearly set out in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt), and must show the 'domain' part of the path.

There are ways to obscure where parts of a page originate.  E.G. use a proxy.

On the other hand, it might be more profitable to investigate why the *perceived* need to 'butcher an URL'.